# What is the initialization path in an object oriented interface that only works with images in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

**This app is supposed to destroy the old frame to draw a new one**.

**In my case the frames are image containers and I show them in 4 different windows, but in the example I only show one as an example, also each instance from** `Img_1` to `Img_60` has its own widgets and these have their own links. Now I have two problems, I hope you can help me please.

1. When it comes to destroying and drawing the new frame, **there are conflicts due to the links of the previous frame**, I was thinking of deactivating them but '''''' doesn't work for me, I'm kind of gross.
2. Where should I initialize the images? [150], I ask this question due to a performance issue as I have noticed that the window takes a long time to open. I appreciate all the people who took the time to read, it doesn't matter if they didn't help me. Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

class Crtl(Frame):
    def__init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self._frame_1 = None
        self._open_1 = False
        self.button1 = Button(self, text='pack 1',
                      command= lambda:self.windows(ImG)
        self.button1 .pack()

    def windows(self, var_1):
        if not self._open_1:
            self.top1 = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.top1 .geometry('200x200')
                                
        container = var_1(self.top1)

        if self._frame_1 is not None:  
            self._frame_1 .destroy()
        self._frame_1 = container
        self._frame_1 .pack()
        self._open_1 = True

class ImG(Frame):
    def__init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.img1 = PhotoImage(file= '60.png')
        self.lbl1 = Label(self, image=self.img1)

        self.master.bind("<Button-1>", self.img_2)

    def img_2(self):
        print('new image N°24')

root = Tk()
app = Ctrl(root, bg='black')
app .pack()
root .mainloop()
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you have 60 different classes, one for each image? Why not pass the name of the image to instantiate a single class 60 times rather than copying the code 60 times?

Comment: I'd only create an instance of a new class when the button to move to that image is pressed. The class should keep a reference to which image it currently has open so that it can open the next image when the next button is pressed. For example if the current image is 50, the next one would be 51.